# set active tab on php pagination

Tags: php, html, css

I need to set an active color on php pagination.

My code is

```
<ul class="pager" role="tablist">
  <li class="previous" onclick="goTo(1);"><a href="#" style="float:none;"><span aria-hidden="true">←</span> Previous</a></li>
  <li class="active">
    <?php
      $article_result2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM blog_table AS b INNER JOIN article_category AS ac ON b.blog_id=ac.blog_id where category_id='$category_id' && lang_id='$lang_id' && status='1' && published_date <= '$today' ORDER BY b.blog_id DESC");
      $count=mysqli_num_rows($article_result2);
      $count=$count/4;
      $count=ceil($count);
      $active=1;
      for($pg=1;$pg<=$count;$pg++)
      {
    ?>
    <a aria-controls="tab2" href="sub-category.php?page=<?php echo $pg;?>&subcat_id=<?php echo $category_id;?>&lang_id=<?php echo $lang_id;?>" role="tab"><?php echo $pg; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </li>
  <li class="next" onclick="goTo(2);">
    <a href="#" style="float:none;">Next <span aria-hidden="true">→</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I add active class on `<li>` it affects on all tabs. I need to add this class on currently active tab, that will always change on selecting the item.

Comment: Improved code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Because you're writing  inside your for() loop, and the for() loop is inside , therefore no matter which one tab you click, even if you don't click anything, all the tabs are set "active"......

You should try to use for() loop to create

lists, and try to "active" the tab you want to activate dynamically inside the loop.